# Yubikey tutorial for elementaryOS

Tags: greeter, full-disk-encryption

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for configuring elementaryOS with Yubikeys? I just bought a 2-pack of the Yubikey 5 NFC and would like to set up stuff like full disk encryption, lightdm login and FIDO U2F authentication support.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up collecting bits and pieces from a number of sites and checking it in as a README file in a Github repository: https://github.com/carniz/ubuntu-yubikey-setup

Hope this can help someone else who wants to configure elementaryOS with Yubikeys.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu Linux Login Guide - Challenge Response**

https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000011355-ubuntu-linux-login-guide-challenge-response

**Enabling the Yubico PPA on Ubuntu**

https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000010964-enabling-the-yubico-ppa-on-ubuntu

**Ubuntu Linux Login Guide - U2F**

https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000011356-ubuntu-linux-login-guide-u2f

**Using Your U2F YubiKey with Linux**

https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006449-using-your-u2f-yubikey-with-linux

---

**Ubuntu - Configure yubikey authentication on Linux**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ac65PmlzTIw

**System wide two factor security Ubuntu**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3p5Wo9KtpAk

---

**Let me search it for you**

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yubikey+ubuntu

---

About full disk encryption, you didn't ask for it just explained what you wanted to achieve. But is another different topic

Answer (score 0):

I believe these will help,
1.  [Official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~yubico/+archive/ubuntu/stable)
2. [YubiKey for Two-Factor Secure Shell Authentication](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/how-to-use-yubikey-for-two-factor-ssh-authentication/)